# Error "Trying to access array offset on value of type bool" solo en PHP 7.4 y no en PHP 7.0 o 7.2

Tags: php, pdo

Tengo este error en PHP 7.4. He intentado varias cosas pero no me funciona.

El error es éste:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in C:\xampp7.47.4\htdocs\proyecto\vistas\plantilla.php on line 65

El error está en esta línea:

```
if($validarCorreo ["email_encriptado"] == $_GET["ruta"]){
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en el código en esa línea:

```
  $item = "email_encriptado";
  $valor = $_GET["ruta"];

  $validarCorreo = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor);

  if($validarCorreo ["email_encriptado"] == $_GET["ruta"]){


    $id = $validarCorreo["id_usuario"];
    $item = "verificacion";
    $valor = 1;

    $respuesta = ControladorUsuarios::ctrActualizarUsuario($id, $item, $valor);

    if($respuesta == "ok"){

      echo'<script>

          swal.fire({
              icon:"success",
                title: "¡CORRECTO!",
                text: "¡Su cuenta ha sido verificada, ya puede ingresar al sistema!",
                showConfirmButton: true,
              confirmButtonText: "Cerrar"
              
          }).then(function(result){

              if(result.value){   
                  window.location = "'.$ruta.'ingreso"
                } 
          });

        </script>';

      return;

    }
  
  }
```

Ésta es la consulta en el modelo:

```
    /*=============================================
    Actualizar usuario
    =============================================*/

    static public function mdlActualizarUsuario($tabla, $id, $item, $valor){

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET $item = :$item WHERE id_usuario = :id_usuario");

        $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt -> bindParam(":id_usuario", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if($stmt -> execute()){

            return "ok";

        }else{

            return print_r(Conexion::conectar()->errorInfo());

        }

        $stmt-> close();

        $stmt = null;
        
    }
```

Aquí el controlador:

```
  /*=============================================
  ACTUALIZAR USUARIO
  =============================================*/
  static public function ctrActualizarUsuario($id, $item, $valor){

    $tabla = "registrousuarios";

    $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlActualizarUsuario($tabla, $id, $item, $valor);

    return $respuesta;
```

Y el mostrar usuarios del controlador:

```
  /*=============================================
  Mostrar Usuarios
  =============================================*/

  static public function ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor){
  
    $tabla = "registrousuarios";

    $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor);

    return $respuesta;

  }
```

Modelo de mostrar usuarios:

```
/*=============================================
    Mostrar Usuarios
    =============================================*/

    static public function mdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor){

        if($item != null && $valor != null){

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item");

            $stmt->bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetch();

        }else{

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }

        $stmt-> close();

        $stmt = null;

    }
```

Comment: Este código parece estar correcto ¿Cuál es tu otro código?

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la línea del problema?

Comment: if($validarCorreo ["email_encriptado"] == $_GET["ruta"]){

Comment: Imagino que `$validarCorreo` es el resultado de una consulta SQL realizada en `ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios()`, ¿verdad?. No has comprobado el resultado de dicha consulta, es muy probable que algo esté mal en ella.

Comment: sii pero en la version de php 7.0 y 7.2 no me sale ese error solo en la 7.3 y la 7.4

Comment: Pues hasta que no compartas el código de dicha función de tu controlador no podremos ayudarte a solucionar el problema raíz, que no está localizado en esa línea, si no antes.

Comment: Te has equivocado, debes compartir el código de `ctrMostrarUsuarios()`, pero has compartido el código de `mdlActualizarUsuario()`.

Comment: es del controlador

Comment: /*=============================================
  ACTUALIZAR USUARIO
  =============================================*/
  static public function ctrActualizarUsuario($id, $item, $valor){

    $tabla = "registrousuarios";

    $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlActualizarUsuario($tabla, $id, $item, $valor);

    return $respuesta;

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para agregar el código. En las respuestas no se puede teclear código (o, al menos, no se lee ni comprende correctamente).

Comment: ESTABA EN ESO LISTO

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que ese código te funciona perfectamente en PHP 7.2 y PHP 7.0? Teóricamente no debería funcionar en ningún PHP, ya que nunca devuelves el resultado de la consulta a la función llamante y, además, un `UPDATE` no devuelve un registro con datos como lo haría un `SELECT`.

Comment: funciona perfectamente, lo mas es que me funciona aun con ese error

Comment: Perdona, no me di cuenta que de nuevo te habías equivocado de función. Necesitamos el código de `mdlMostrarUsuarios()`, ya que `ctrMostrarUsuarios()` hace uso de ella para obtener el valor que devuelve.

Comment: LISTO YA LO PUSE EN LA PREGUNTA

Answer (score 2):

Tu problema se origina en la siguiente línea:

```
$validarCorreo = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor);
```

La llamada está devolviendo `true` o `false` (un valor booleano), de modo que no es posible acceder a un elemento de un valor booleano como si se tratara de una matriz justo en la línea siguiente:

```
if ($validarCorreo["email_encriptado"] == $_GET["ruta"]) {
```

Si la llamada a `ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios()` realiza una consulta SQL es muy probable que no estés comprobando su resultado de manera adecuada.

---

Edito (tras agregar el código necesario):

Estás haciendo varias cosas mal en tu código, entre ellas no comprobar el resultado de la consulta SQL.

```
static public function mdlMostrarUsuarios($tabla, $item, $valor)
{
    /* Solo compruebas si valen null, pero podrían estar vacíos */
    if (empty($item) === false && empty($valor) === false) {
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE $item = :$item"
        );
        $stmt->bindParam(":". $item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
            /* Si la consulta falló, habrá que hacer algo */
            die(
                htmlspecialchars(implode(", ", $stmt->errorInfo()))
            );
        }
        return $stmt->fetch();
    } else {
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla");
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
            /* Si la consulta falló, habrá que hacer algo */
            die(
                htmlspecialchars(implode(", ", $stmt->errorInfo()))
            );
        }
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
    /* Este código de aquí abajo es completamente inútil, nunca se ejecutará */
    $stmt-> close();
    $stmt = null;
}
```

Además, estás devolviendo tres tipos de datos en tu función (deberías evitar este tipo de prácticas):

- Si `$item` y `$valor` NO están vacíos (antes comprobabas si eran nulos) devuelves:

  - Un único registro, una matriz unidimensional con los campos del único registro.
  - **`false` en caso de que no hayas encontrado ninguno**.
- Si están vacíos entonces devuelves:

  - Todos los registros de la tabla, una matriz multidimensional con un elemento por registro y cada registro con sus campos de la tabla.

De modo que también podrías obtener un `false` en caso de que no hayas obtenido ningún registro como resultado, por lo que tu `if` debería contemplarlo:

```
if ($validarCorreo === false) {
    /* Mensaje advirtiendo que no se encontró el registro */
} else if ($validarCorreo ["email_encriptado"] == $_GET["ruta"]){
    /* Tu código habitual */
} else {
    /* ¡¡Mensaje o acción cuando no coinciden!! */
}
```

---

Última edición:

Tras haber visto varias veces el código y haber entendido el motivo por el que haces estas líneas:

```
<?php
$item = "email_encriptado";
$valor = $_GET["ruta"];

$validarCorreo = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor);

if($validarCorreo ["email_encriptado"] == $_GET["ruta"]){
```

Veo que se puede simplificar enormemente de esta manera:

```
<?php
/* No es necesario hacer uso de variables intermedias */
$validarCorreo = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarios(
    "email_encriptado",
    $_GET["ruta"]
);
if ($validarCorreo === false) {
    /* No se encontró el usuario */
} else {
    /* Se encontró el usuario y no es necesario comprobar que el campo
    "email_encriptado" del registro vale lo mismo que $_GET["ruta"] porque
    precisamente esa es la condición de búsqueda "WHERE" */
}
```

Comment: /*=============================================
 Actualizar usuario
 =============================================*/

 static public function mdlActualizarUsuario($tabla, $id, $item, $valor){

  $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("UPDATE $tabla SET $item = :$item WHERE id_usuario = :id_usuario");

  $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt -> bindParam(":id_usuario", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

  if($stmt -> execute()){

   return "ok";

  }else{

   return print_r(Conexion::conectar()->errorInfo());

  }

  $stmt-> close();

  $stmt = null;
  
 ]

Comment: YA LA AGREGUE A LA PREGUNTA

Comment: He editado la respuesta con tu código corregido (también he aplicado [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), deberías acostumbrarte a usarlo siempre). Mi respuesta inicial sigue siendo válida, el problema es que falla la consulta SQL, así que con este código, a parte de explicarte que produce el error, te ayudará a encontrar el error. También te he indicado que `$stmt-> close();` y `$stmt = null;` nunca se ejecutarán, porque los `return` devuelven el control a la función llamante mucho antes.

Comment: He hecho una última edición ahora que he tomado consciencia del conjunto (no veía la relación entre el campo `email_cifrado` y `$_GET["ruta"]`. Tu código puede reducir su complejidad ya que tu SQL está buscando un registro cuyo campo `email_cifrado` calga `$_GET["ruta"]`, por lo que si se recibe un registro es porque se cumple esa condición, y si se recibe `false` es porque no se encontró dicho registro. Hacer de nuevo la comprobación en un `if` es redundante (y falla cuando no recibes un registro).

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la respuesta añadi esta linea solucionando el error

```
 if(is_array($validarCorreo) && $validarCorreo["email_encriptado"] == $_GET["ruta"]){
```

Comment: Realmente esa no es la solución, es un parche. `$validarCorreo` vale `false` por algún motivo, y debes encontrar el motivo por el que adquirió ese valor.

Comment: si es que eso esta muy sospechoso

Comment: sería bueno que evalúes que te da `errorInfo` el te debe auxiliar en detectar que ocurre @luisfernando

Comment: Estoy con @BetaM. Es justo lo que he propuesto en mi respuesta. El origen del problema está en que la consulta SQL está fallando y devuelve `false`, por lo que antes de "tapar" ese fallo, deberías corregirlo, ya que estás perdiendo esa funcionalidad en tu aplicación.

Comment: si estoy revisando esa consulta haber si logro arreglarlo de raiz

Comment: He vuelto a edita mi respuesta ya que existe otro motivo por el que puedes estar obtenido un `false`, y es cuando no recibes ningún registro en tu consulta. Te he propuesto un método de detectarlo y mostrar un mensaje adecuado o hacer lo que creas pertinente en ese caso.

Comment: Gracias esa respuesta tuya quito el error de igual manera

Comment: He hecho una última edición ahora que he tomado consciencia del conjunto (no veía la relación entre el campo `email_cifrado` y `$_GET["ruta"]`. Tu código puede reducir su complejidad ya que tu SQL está buscando un registro cuyo campo `email_cifrado` calga `$_GET["ruta"]`, por lo que si se recibe un registro es porque se cumple esa condición, y si se recibe `false` es porque no se encontró dicho registro. Hacer de nuevo la comprobación en un `if` es redundante (y falla cuando no recibes un registro).